# Why is readlineInterface.question() running early?

Tags: node.js, terminal, callback, readline

I have been working on a game called "Secret Message", wherein a player must guess a secret message hidden among several text files in a directory. My app is a node module so that I can use the Chalk5 ESM. I am using the readline callback API in order to evaluate user input.

I initialized a readline interface using `process.stdin` and `process.stdout` as my `input` and `output` respectively. My issue is that whenever I use the `question()` method, my code seems to run without my input. The same happens whenever I use the Node REPL; After I create a new interface using readline.createInterface, anything I text in the terminal gets doubled. For instance:

```
> const rl = require('readline')
// output: undefined
> const channel = rl.createInterface({input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout})
// output: undefined
```

Then, attempting to type `channel.question( ... )` results in:

```
// This is my real input.
> cchaannnneell..qquueessttiioonn(())
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Here is the relevant code section for the actual game:

```
function getDirParameter(dirParameter, directoryQuery) {
  let userChoice;
  channel.question(directoryQuery, (dirChoice) => {
    userChoice = dirChoice;
    console.log(dirChoice);
    switch(dirChoice) {
      case 'current':
        dirParameter = __dirname;
        break;
      case 'custom':
        console.log('User chose "custom".');
        break; 
      default: 
        console.error('Invalid option.');
        break;
    }
    channel.close();
  });
  
  return userChoice;
}
```

I have tried logging the user input before closing the interface. The terminal ends up logging nothing.

Comment: You are running `searchParameters.directoryPath = evaluateCustomPath();` BEFORE `channel.question()` completes.  `channel.question()` is non-blocking and asynchronous.  It returns before it's done.  You would have to close the channel inside the callback, not after it.

Comment: @jfriend00 I renamed the `evaluateCustomPath()` function to `getCustomPath()`, then refactored my code so that I was calling `const dirParameter = await getDirParameter(searchParameters.directoryPath, directoryQuery);`. I made sure to close the channel inside of the function, but the code still runs as if there is input before I type anything into the terminal.

Comment: `await` doesn't do anything useful unless it's awaiting a promise that resolves when the asynchronous code is done and I don't see any promises in this code.  So, in whatever refactor you did, it doesn't sound like the `await` is doing anything and thus you still have the problem.

Comment: I ended up completely rewriting the function giving me trouble. I had previously put the code into an asynchronous function and had `getCustomPath()` return a promise, so there was a purpose behind the await statement. Now everything is synchronous and the code is still giving me trouble. I rewrote the original post to reflect the chances to `getDirParameter()` , which had been the source of my problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you show looks incomplete because you don't actually do anything different based on the `switch()` statement.  But, here's a promisified version of that function:

```
async function getDirParameter(channel, dirParameter, directoryQuery) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        channel.question(directoryQuery, (dirChoice) => {
            console.log(dirChoice);
            switch (dirChoice) {
                case 'current':
                    dirParameter = __dirname;
                    break;
                case 'custom':
                    console.log('User chose "custom".');
                    break;
                default:
                    console.error('Invalid option.');
                    break;
            }
            resolve(dirChoice);
        });
    });
}
```

You would use this inside an `async` function like this:

```
const dirChoice = await getDirParameter(channel, dirQuery);
```

Note, this version of the function does not close the channel because it seems like the code that opens the channel should be the code that closes the channel and this function may want to be used more than once on the same channel.  That's a design choice for you to decide on, but it made sense to me so I did the rewrite that way.

P.S. Assigning to a function parameter like `dirParameter` and then not doing anything else with dirParameter doesn't actually accomplish anything so basically, you `swtich()` statement isn't accomplishing anything.  Maybe there's more code there to come...

Note: Starting with nodejs v17, there is an experimental interface for `rl.question()` that already returns a promise.

Comment: So my main fix should be to create the channel inside of the asynchronous function that calls getDirParameter? I had created `channel` globally previously, so the channel param on `getDirParameter()` is redundant here, unless the key is for me to create it within the scope of my calling function.

Comment: Alright, having a globally declared readline interface seemed to be the issue. Thank you! I wish I had enough 'reputation' to upvote you.

Comment: @MB1721 - You can (at any reputation level), accept an answer to your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.